# Angular 4 app on S3 denied access after redirect

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I've built a simple angular 4 app that uses firebase as my authentication. And I use `loginWithRedirect` because `loginWithPopup` didn't work really on my cell phone.

But the problem I'm running into is the redirect leaves the page, obviously, to authenticate, and then comes back to `mysite.com/login` but because its a SPA `/login` doesn't exist to the bucket I'm guessing.

I've added this redirection rule, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <HostName>mysite.cloudfront.net</HostName>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>#!/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>403</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <HostName>mysite.cloudfront.net</HostName>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>#!/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

I'm redirecting on 403 also because thats the error I keep getting. Then I've added `<script>
  history.pushState({}, "entry page", location.hash.substring(1));
</script>` to the top of my index.html file (solution from another stackoverflow question).

But still getting the 403. I don't have the app set up to use hashbangs to begin with and would like to not have to.

The error message I recieve:

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>0D98B2536B28C06D</RequestId>
    <HostId>8nhnAtzaLxPvWcV3f8zqc=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Edit: A dirty fix I have is to just right before sending the user to google to authenticate, navigate to '/' so thats where google redirects back to. It'd be nice if there was a way to tell google where to redirect back to. Is there?

Comment: I've found the steps at https://keita.blog/2015/11/24/hosting-a-single-page-app-on-s3-with-proper-urls/ work really well if you put the S3 behind Cloudfront

Comment: if I'm not mistaken,  it's possible to define you callback (url to redirect after authenticate) on the console of you application. I don't know how firebase works in this matter but if you have control over the callback endpoint you can redirect to whatever URL you want.

Comment: @user184994 Thanks! that was super easy and worked pretty well so far!

Comment: @ElmerDantas as far as I've been able to see, there isn't a way (using firebase) to provide a redirect url. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

We need add the read access policy in the permissions > bucket policy as mentioned in this documentation. Give it a try

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html

`{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
    "Sid":"PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET-NAME/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}`