# I get invalid json error when i try to add read access policy in s3 permission tab

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to AWS. I created s3 bucket - public where i stored all my images which i want to show on my front end page. But when i try to show them on the front end page with the s3 object url i get 403 forbidden error.

I googled and i found answer

[Angular 4 app on S3 denied access after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48118958/angular-4-app-on-s3-denied-access-after-redirect)

The guy there says that we should add read access policy in the permissions tab.

So i did exactly like he said but when i paste this object like he suggest in the CORS tab

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::somename/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

and click save changes i get error

```
The CORS configuration must be written in valid JSON.
```

why in past this was valid JSON and now it is not ? As i said i am new to AWS and don't know how to fix this. Also can somoene tell me why even my s3 bucket is public - i can't access the objects inside publiccly from my front end ?

Comment: This is not CORS, but bucket policy. It should be in `Permissions->Bucket policy`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Obviously i should distinct and learn the difference between this two things. Can you please explain me what are the meanings of the properties inside this json ? I guess Principal": "*" means allow request from every domain in future it should be replaced with my actual domain in production right ? And "Action":["s3:GetObject"], means that i am accepting ONLY GET REQUESTS now from everywhere for my SPECIFIED BUCKET but not post for example ?

Comment: Sure, I will post an answer with extra info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The json document in the question is [bucket policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-overview.html), not CORS, and it should be added as explained in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-bucket-policy.html).

The specific policy that you are using:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::somename/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

has following meaning. Also from [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-overview.html):

> grants **anonymous read permission on all objects** in a bucket. The bucket policy has one statement, which allows the s3:GetObject action (**read permission**) on objects in a bucket named `somename`.  By specifying the **principal with a wild card** (*), the policy grants anonymous access, and should be used carefully. For example, the following bucket policy would make objects publicly accessible.

Further explanation of this specific policy is given in:

- [Granting Read-Only Permission to an Anonymous User](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2)